# Byte manipulation in Python

Tags: python, byte

I have a integer. Lets say,

```
var = 83 #less than 0xff
```

And I have a byte.
So let's say I have byte b and I want to calculate the integer value of

```
 b-=var #b as an integer value , possibly by eval(b)?
```

And then I want to turn it back into a byte, how can I do this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the question, you can do:

```
>>> chr(ord('x') - 83)
'%'
```

where `'x'` is your byte.

If you're on Python 3.x

```
>>> bytes([ord(b'x') - 83])
b'%'
```

Note `ord(b'x')` is the same as `b'x'[0]`

Another example (where the resulting byte is not printable and is shown in the `\x00` form):

```
>>> chr(ord('\x53') - 83)
'\x00'
```

Comment: @JJG You store your bytes in strings or bytestrings (Py3k), right? So, if the result is printable, it'll will appear this way.

Comment: OK. Well, I'm getting an error: ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256) . I don't know why this is happening. Also I'm using Pytohn 2.7

Comment: @JJG that's because you're using a number smaller than 83 and `chr` can't handle negative numbers

Comment: @JJG You can add 256 for negative numbers to wrap around

Comment: Thanks all! I think I did it. I did the +=256 wrap around.